How the given transformation affecting the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2t}{\partial x^2 }$ .....
For transformation $u=x-ct$ and $v=x+ct$ the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2t}{\partial x^2 }$ reduces to
A. $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=0$
B. $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u\partial v}=0$
C.$\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=0$
D.$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v^2}=0$
Actually I am not getting the question...How this transformation should I apply to get the required solution. I think there is some error in the question..Please let me know if it is correct how to approach it...
Thanks in advance!!

Hint : apply the chain rule.

I agree that there is an error in the question: the RHS of the PDE should be $c^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2 }$.

Still not getting can you show me...little....how to do use chain rule here...

From the very scratch.
From $u=x-ct$ and $v=x+ct$ we get
$$
du=dx-c\,dt\,,\quad dv=dx+c\,dt\,.
$$
This can be written as
$$\tag1
(du,dv)=(dx,dt)A
$$
where $A$ is the matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1\\-c&c}\,.
$$
Looking at the formal scalar product
$$
V^x\partial_x+V^t\partial_t=V^u\partial_u+V^v\partial_v
$$
which is an equality between vectors and knowing that the components $V^x,V^t$ transform
into $V^u,V^v$ just like (1)
$$
(V^u,V^v)=(V^x,V^t)A
$$
it becomes clear that the partial derivatives must transform as
$$
{\partial_u\choose\partial_v}=A^{-1}{\partial_x\choose\partial_t}\,.
$$
From
$$
A^{-1}=\frac12\pmatrix{1&-\frac1c\\1&\frac1c}
$$
we find
$$
\partial_u=\frac{\partial_x-\frac1c\partial_t}2\,,\quad\partial_v=\frac{\partial_x+\frac1c\partial_t}2\,.
$$
Then
$$
\partial_u\partial_v=\frac{(\partial_x-\tfrac1c\partial_t)(\partial_x+\frac1c\partial_t)}4=\frac{\partial_x^2-\frac1{c^2}\partial_t^2}{4}\,.
$$
To which of the four PDEs does
$$
\partial_x^2z-\tfrac1{c^2}\partial_t^2z=0
$$
now correspond? This will also fix a typo in your title and at the top of the question.
